# Retorna valor da query em uma variavel

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Preciso retorna o valor de uma consulta da query em uma variavel int, para poder fazer a comparação com a minha TextBox, porem não consigo fazer a comparação pois não pode comparar inteiro(textbox) com um grupo de metodos(jquery), segue meu codigo a baixo.

ControleRota Class:

```
public IList<Rota> ConsultaCarro (int NVeiculoId)
{
    string hql = "SELECT * FROM Rota r WHERE r.NVeiculoId = :NVeiculoId";
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
    query.SetParameter("NVeiculoId", NVeiculoId);
    return query.UniqueResult<Rota>(); 
    return query.List<Rota>();
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Adicionar(RotaModel viewModel)
{
    if (/*Onde entraria o valor da query*/ = viewModel.NVeiculoId)
    {

    }

    if (viewModel.Km_Atual < 85000)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido",
        "A quilometragem precisa ser maior que a anterior");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota();
        dao.Adicionar(rota);
        //return View();
        return RedirectToAction("Form");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDao.Lista();
        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62808/discussion-on-question-by-guilherme-padovam-retorna-valor-da-query-em-uma-variav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelos comentários, acho que é isso que você precisa

```
public ActionResult Adicionar(RotaModel viewModel)
{
    var rotas = ConsultaCarro(viewModel.NVeiculoId);
    // Aqui busca todas as rotas deste veículo

    var maiorRota = rotas.OrderByDescending(r => r.Km_Atual).First();
    // Aqui você tem a última rota cadastrada, considerando a regra geral   

    if (viewModel.Km_Atual < maiorRota.Km_Atual)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido",
        "A quilometragem precisa ser maior que a anterior");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota();
        dao.Adicionar(rota);
        //return View();
        return RedirectToAction("Form");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDao.Lista();
        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado LINQ, mas so uma duvida como ele ira buscar o VeiculoId?

Comment: Mas pra quê buscar? Ele já está em **`viewModel.NVeiculoId`**.

Comment: Então ira me trazer somente o valor daquele veiculo?

Comment: Isso. Não é este o comportamento esperado???

Comment: Não precisa chamar no sql o veiculoid pra trazer somente os valores daquele veiculo?

Comment: Sim, é que eu estava imaginando umas trezentas linhas de codigo kkk

Comment: Mas é pra isso que serve o parâmetro no método `ConsultaCarro`

Comment: Entendi, não tem problema se o sql for string não?

Comment: Nao, jow. Não tem relação

Comment: Vou testar o codigo, informo se houver algum erro, rezo pra não ter

Comment: LINQ quando foi adicionar um km em um veiculo que não tenha valor nenhum teria que fazer um outro adicionar ou um if?

Comment: Deu certo, o codigo, somente deu problema quando vai adicionar um km em um veiculo que não tem nada registrado

Comment: LINQ muito obrigado, funciono perfeitamento, dei uma ajustada que quando for registrado o veiculo, ele sempre vai coloca 0 km, muito obrigado mesmo.